# React SSR, Form onSubmit handler does not work(form gets submitted) before bundled js file loads

Tags: reactjs

I am facing this issue with a slower network connection. I am loading HTML content using SSR on the first load. So, until my bundled app js loads, no event handler works. For the workaround, I disabled the button and enabled it in ***componentDidMount***. This works fine but render will be called twice. Is this the right approach or can be done in a better way?

This is my code,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LogIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'Please write an essay about your favorite DOM element.',
      allowLogin: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ allowLogin: true });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('User name is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          User Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={!this.state.allowLogin}/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default LogIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue which events triggered before client-side hydration.
A workaround:

```
<iframe name="dummy_frame" className="dummy_frame" src="about:blank" />
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} target="dummy_frame">
    .....
</form>
```

In the css file:

```
.dummy_frame {
    display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer from @Yahel Yechieli works but under the hood, it triggers GET request with values from inputs.
In my opinion will be better to disable the native event for the form.

Example:
index.html

```
  document.querySelectorAll('.SSRSubmit').forEach(function(element) {
    element.onsubmit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      return false;
  };});
```

App.ts

```
<form className="SSRSubmit"></form>
```